# Approximating a continuous function by a sawtooth function

Tags: general-topology, continuity, metric-spaces, proof-explanation, uniform-continuity

> I need to understand a proof in the book "Lecture notes on topology and geometry" by Singer and Thorpe, from 2.5 Applications

**Theorem 1:** There exists a continuous real-valued function $f\in C([0,1])$ such that $f$ has a derivative in no point of $[0,1]$.

*Proof:* Define for all $n\in \mathbb{N}$ the set
$$
C_n
=\left\{f\in \mathcal{C}([0,1]): \Big|\dfrac{f(t+h)-f(t)}{h}\Big|\leqslant n,\text{for some $t$ and all $h$ with $t+h$ $\in [0,1]$} \right\}
$$

Show that $C_n$ is nowhere dense for each $n$, then since $C([0,1])$ is a complete metric space we have
$$
\mathcal{C}([0,1])\neq \bigcup_{n\in \mathbb{N}} C_n
$$ 
it must exists a function $f\in \mathcal{C}([0,1])$ such that $f\notin C_n$ for all $n$ and this means it has no derivative.

1. I understand why this last remark is true because if $f\notin C_n$ for all $n$ then
   $$
   \Big|\dfrac{f(t+h)-f(t)}{h}\Big|> n
   $$ and then

$$\limsup_{h\rightarrow0}\Big|\dfrac{f(t+h)-f(t)}{h}\Big|=\infty$$ for all $t\in [0,1]$ thus the derivative does not exists.

2. I understand how to show that $\overline C_n=C_n$ because is well explained in the book, I must considere a sequence $\{f_k\}$ in $C_n$ which converges to $f$ and show that $f\in C_n$.

I have a problem showing that $C_n$ is nowhere dense, the book says that given any $\epsilon >0$ and any $g\in C_n$ there exists $f \in C([0,1])$ such that $||f-g||<\epsilon$ and $f\notin C_n$, and suggest i should do that by approximating $g$ (using the fact that $g$ is uniformly continuous) by a piecewise linear function $g_1$ and then use a "sawtooth" function for each linear piece of $g_1$
 and then "to patch". Also note that the norm is $||f||=sup|f(x)|$ for all $x\in [0,1]$

I ask for an explanation on this last remark, a good reference to understand it or any other help that you can provide.

Comment: This is just a visualization: function $f$ must satisfy $||f-g||<\epsilon$. Function $g_1$ is a good try, since it is linear, but it can have small derivatives at some points. Notice that a piecewise linear $f \notin C_n$ needs to have angular coeficient with modulus greater than $n$, everywhere. The idea is then to build $f$ from $g_1$ by replacing each linear piece by a new piecewise linear with same starting and ending, but always having high angular coeficient. For a similar construction, check [Munkres](https://www.amazon.com/Topology-2nd-James-Munkres/dp/0131816292), page 304.