# Can you approximate $\cos(x)$ on $\mathbb{R}$ in the space of periodic sawtooth functions?

Tags: continuity, fourier-series, approximation, periodic-functions

Let any function of the form $x \mapsto 1-\frac{2x}{L}$ for $x \in (kL, (k+1)L)$ for all integers $k$ and some period $L > 0$ be referred to as *periodic sawtooth*.

Let $\mathcal{S}$ be the space of sawtooth functions of arbitrary periods closed under finite linear combinations.

I'm working on a problem in which I could greatly benefit from a result similar to the following:

> Let $f(x)$ be a piecewise continuous periodic function with period $L$. Then there exists a sequence of sawtooths $(s_n)_{n \geq 1}$ drawn from $\mathcal{S}$ such that
> $$
> f(x) = \lim_{n \to \infty}s_n(x)
> $$
> for all $x \in \mathbb{R}$, i.e. the convergence is pointwise.

[This question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3008262/approximating-a-continuous-function-by-a-sawtooth-function) seemed to have already been asked, but on a closer inspection it seems that the author of that post didn't have the additional requirement of the sawtooth being periodic, and thus had the freedom of building piece-wise linear approximations by scaling, reverting and translating individual sawtooths.

**My attempt:** Periodicity suggests that Fourier Convergence Theorem could be useful. Indeed, if I could approximate just $\cos(x)$, I think I could make the rest of it work. I tried building a "periodic step function" (a step function that repeats itself periodically) out of sawtooths, but either I'm missing something, or it's really hard.

**Questions:**

1. Would anyone happen to have any insight on the feasibility of the above blockquoted problem?
2. Does anyone have any idea whether periodic sawtooth could be used to approximate at least $\cos(x)$? Uniform convergence is not necessary, in fact I would readily settle for pointwise convergence.
3. Does anybody know whether it is possible to use periodic sawtooth to build a periodic step function? From that, the rest would follow -- or so it seems to me.